# Unable to install rdkafka on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I want to install [rdkafka](https://arnaud-lb.github.io/php-rdkafka/phpdoc/rdkafka.installation.html)

[Upon running the command as per the instructions: `sudo pecl install rdkafka`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw8cF.png)

I have installed pecl using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

**Quick Install Steps:**

**Step 1 Install PHP pecl and pear commands:**

```
sudo apt install php-pear
```

**Step 2 Install librdkafka**

```
sudo apt-get install -y librdkafka-dev
```

**Step 3 Install PECL-package**

```
sudo pecl install rdkafka
```

**Step4 Enable PHP-extension in PHP config. Add to php.ini**

```
extension=rdkafka.so
```

**Step 4 Restart apache server**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I made all that steps but after all i get error: ```PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'rdkafka.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/rdkafka.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/rdkafka.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/rdkafka.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/rdkafka.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0```

Answer (score 2):

Before doing that install librdkafka . linux command  sudo apt-get install librdkafka . After that try the same command as you mentioned using pecl. Hope it should work.

For more detail use this link: https://arnaud-lb.github.io/php-rdkafka/phpdoc/book.rdkafka.html

Comment: Hi!
I installed librdkafka.
After that I executed the command: `sudo pecl install rdkafka`
Now, I am getting the error: 
`In file included from /usr/include/php5/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:27:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/rdkafka/metadata_broker.c:27:
/usr/include/php5/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [metadata_broker.lo] Error 1
ERROR: make' failed
`

Comment: folow this link : https://arnaud-lb.github.io/php-rdkafka/phpdoc/rdkafka.installation.pecl.html